# create data table using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

let's say I have a `data.table`

```
DT=data.table(name = sample(letters[1:25],30,replace=T), value =rnorm(3000))
```

I want to split the `DT` by names and create new DTs like name `DT_a`,`DT_b` corresponding to the name value. So how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `list2env`

```
lst <-split(DT, DT$name)
list2env(setNames(lst, paste0("DT_", names(lst))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

But, it is recommended to keep it in a `list` rather than creating multiple datasets in the global environment.  However, if this is just for understanding the possibility of creating objects, `list2env` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DTs = split(DT, DT$name)
lapply(names(DTs), function(x) assign(paste0('DT_',x), DTs[[x]], envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

Comment: I have one question,why should we add  .globalenv? I tried to remove it,and   returned the wrong result

Comment: Without it the assignment happens "inside" the function only. Same reason that `f = function() {x = 5}; f()` can't create a variable `x`

Comment: Don't use a function with a side effect of assigning into the global environment in `lapply` (or ever, really).

Comment: @Roland reason?

Comment: `lapply` is useful if you need a list of the function results. (Incidentally, that's what OP should use if they must `split` at all, which I doubt.) Otherwise, a `for` loop is what should be used. But, side effects like this are obvious signs that you are using the wrong approach in R. Keep the global environment clean of objects that you don't create yourself explicitly. Otherwise, you write code that is hard to debug and sooner or later will give you a nasty surprise.